# ADO.NET Entity Framework: Create an Object Using the Static Create Method (C#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I wrote this:

```
using (GuiaMovilEntities guiaEntity = new GuiaMovilEntities())
{
   try
   {
     Cliente cliente = 
        Cliente.CreateCliente(-1, datosCliente.Email, datosCliente.Password);
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
```

It's unfinished.

If table Cliente (represented by Cliente object) has its first row (clienteID) as IDENTITY column.

Is it correct to put -1 as clienteID value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity parameters are auto-generated - you shouldn't need to specify the value yourself.

Comment: So you should use the default static Create method that the entity framework object creates or do you just enter in 0 as the ID?

Comment: I'd imagine that if it's auto-generated, you don't need to enter anything at all. Certainly don't assign `0` to the ID.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to be the case for me when I generate an .edmx from the database I have, though perhaps that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente
{
    Email = datosCliente.Email,
    Password = datosCliente.Password
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't ever need to set the Id.  Remove the parameter from the factory method and leave the Id value as the default (zero in this case I imagine).

Answer (score 0):

if you really want a undefined id which is not 0, such as -1, you could implement the default constructor for your entity and set it there.